# Database is disappearing from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, phpmyadmin, wampserver

We've build an application using wampserver, PHP and MySQL. We are working offline in the meantime for funds reasons and can't upload it online with a dedicated IP address. Each few days, we receive a PHP error on the LOGIN page saying that there isn't a database named `X`.

We went to the phpmyadmin and the shock was that the database isn't there. 
We tried to see if it is hidden in the config file of PHPmyadmin, but it isn't.

Then, we deleted `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` from the mysql data bin directory, and after restarting the computer, the database appeared again normally.

After few days, the same thing happens. We deleted the both files but this time the database didn't appeared in wamp. We glad that we backuped the data last time, but there is a full week data that may be lost now.

What is the problem ? Is it a computer virus or wampserver needs to be installed again ?

Error:

> #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. — The server is not responding (or the local
>   server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: May be it is the problem of computer virus.

Comment: Can I get back the full week data with something ? One week data would take too much time to re-add them

Comment: That's true but if your files were infected by virus then no way to get back. Just took backup of everyday and feel relax.

Comment: Not sure about this, but are you running short of disk space on the machine?

Comment: Please see this: I am having the following error: ` #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).`

Comment: try re-installing wamp